# Ansible where do PreferredAuthentications SSH settings come from?

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm running a standard ansible (v2.3.1) playbook using SSH username and password settings. When using the '-vvvv' setting i can see these SSH commands getting generated

```
EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s 
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=2222 
-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no 
-o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey 
-o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=dc_user -o ConnectTimeout=10
```

In the case above, where are the 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey' settings getting pulled from. I believe these come from the client SSH config settings but is this correct?

I understand that i can override the ssh arguments by defining this in my 'ansaible.cfg'

```
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh=True
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey
```

Can someone explain this to me?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm observe that `-o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey` is hard coded in the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/e99db084f445d896fdfe53c90448a3eb80d4f304/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py#L552)

If you override `ssh_args` in `ansible.cfg` to `-o PreferredAuthentications=publickey` is added to the ssh command line but this doesn't replace `-o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey`

Example:

```
$ grep ssh_args /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg 
#ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o     PreferredAuthentications=publickey
$ ansible rhel7a -m ping -vvvv |grep EXEC
<rhel7a> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=vagrant -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/user/.ansible/cp/13dd447a86 rhel7a '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
```